# iOS - Why reloadData tableView data on first application load?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a simple Flickr app that gets some data from their API and displays it on a tableview instance. Here's a piece of the code for the TableViewController subclass.

```
var photos = [FlickrPhotoModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getFlickrPhotos()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
private func getFlickrPhotos() {
    DataProvider.fetchFlickrPhotos { (error: NSError?, data: [FlickrPhotoModel]?) in

        //data is received
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if error == nil {
                self.photos = data!
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The application does not seem to load the data if the { tableView.reloadData() } line is removed. Does anyone know why this would happen since I call getFlickrPhotos() within viewDidLoad(). I believe I am also dispatching from the background thread in the appropriate place. Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

**EDIT -- Data Provider code**

```
class func fetchFlickrPhotos(onCompletion: FlickrResponse) {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=\(Keys.apikey)&per_page=25&format=json&nojsoncallback=1")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured trying to fetch photos")
            onCompletion(error, nil)
            return
        }

        do {

            let jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            let photosContainer = jsonResults!["photos"] as? NSDictionary
            let photoArray = photosContainer!["photo"] as? [NSDictionary]

            let flickrPhoto: [FlickrPhotoModel] = photoArray!.map{
                photo in

                let id = photo["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let farm = photo["farm"] as? Int ?? 0
                let secret = photo["secret"] as? String ?? ""
                let server = photo["server"] as? String ?? ""
                var title = photo["title"] as? String ?? "No title available"
                if title == "" {
                    title = "No title available"
                }

                let model = FlickrPhotoModel(id: id, farm: farm, server: server, secret: secret, title: title)
                return model
            }

            //the request was successful and flickrPhoto contains the data
            onCompletion(nil, flickrPhoto)



        } catch let conversionError as NSError {
            print("Error parsing json results")
            onCompletion(conversionError, nil)

        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that API, but it looks like the `fetchFlickrPhotos` method is called asynchronously on a background thread. That means that the rest of the application will not wait for it to finish before moving on. `viewDidLoad` will call the method, but then move on without waiting for it to finish.

The completion handler that you provide is called *after* the photos are done downloading which, depending on the number and size of the photos, could be seconds later. So `reloadData` is necessary to refresh the table view after the photos are actually done downloading.

Comment: How are you aware that fetchFlickrPhotos is called on a background thread? I've edited my original post to include code for the DataProvider class. Is it because NSUrlSession runs on a background thread?

Comment: Couple reasons...first, it includes a callback function. The only reason for having a callback is if the function is asynchronous. And before updating the table view, the callback retrieves the main queue, which means it must have been running on something other than the main queue. Last, it's a pretty common pattern...large downloads ought to always be done asynchronously and in the background to avoid blocking the main queue, so I was expecting those things to begin with.

Comment: Thanks Roman! This makes so much sense now that you explained it that way. Could I send you this code to get further improvements on it? I can send it via email to since I do not have it on github yet. you can send me your email address on tarang9211@gmail.com if you don't want to share you email here. thanks a ton!